# Strong continuity of an automorphism group on a $C^\ast$-algebra (quantum dynamics)

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, mathematical-physics, operator-algebras

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $T : H \supseteq \mathrm{dom}(T) \to H$ be a self-adjoint linear operator on $H$. Define a one-parameter group $(\tau_t)_{t \in \mathbb{R}}$ of $\ast$-automorphisms on the $C^\ast$-algebra $\mathscr{B}(H)$ of bounded operators on $H$ by setting
$$
\tau_t(A) = e^{i t T} A \, e^{- i t T}
$$
for all $A \in \mathscr{B}(H)$, $t \in \mathbb{R}$. I came across the following statement in some book: *the group $(\tau_t)$ is strongly continuous on $\mathscr{B}(H)$ if and only if the operator $T$ is bounded on $H$*.

**Question:** How can one prove this equivalence, especially the implication that strong continuity implies boundedness of $T$?

Since $T$ is self-adjoint, it would suffice to show that $\mathrm{dom}(T) = H$. I thought about mimicking the well-known proof of the fact that a strongly continuous one-parameter group of operators is uniformly continuous iff its generator is defined everywhere, but this did not work out as I hoped.

*Context of the question:* If $T$ is interpreted as the Hamiltonian of a quantum system, then the group $(\tau_t)$ describes the time evolution of (bounded) observables of the system. Hence, the above statement implies that the quantum dynamical system $(\mathscr{B}(H), \tau_t)$ is a $C^\ast$-dynamical system iff $T$ is bounded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\def\abajo{\\[0.2cm]}\def\e{\varepsilon}$ Suppose that $T$ is unbounded. Note first that if $\|T-T_0\|<\e$ and $TT_0=T_0T$, then
\begin{align}
\|e^{itT}Ae^{-itT}-e^{itT_0}Ae^{-itT_0}\|
&\leq\|e^{itT}Ae^{-itT}-e^{itT_0}Ae^{-itT}\|
+
\|e^{itT_0}Ae^{-itT}-e^{itT_0}Ae^{-itT_0}\|\abajo
&=\|e^{itT}A-e^{itT_0}A\|
+
\|Ae^{-itT}-Ae^{-itT_0}\|\abajo
&\leq\|e^{itT}-e^{itT_0}\|\,\|A\|
+
\|e^{-itT}-e^{-itT_0}\|\,\|A\|\abajo
&=\|e^{it(T-T_0)}-I\|\,\|A\|
+
\|I-e^{-it(T-T_0)}\|\,\|A\|.
\end{align}
The above allows us to replace, without loss of generality, $T$ with a discretized version (via the Spectral Theorem, see details at the end). That is, we assume
$$\tag1
T=\sum_n t_n\,E_{nn},
$$
where the $E_{nn}$ are pairwise orthogonal rank-one projections, and $\{t_n\}$ is an unbounded sequence of real numbers. This gives us
$$
e^{ihT}=\sum_ne^{iht_n}E_{nn}.
$$

By fixing an appropriate orthonormal basis, we extend the $E_{nn}$ to a system of matrix units $\{E_{kj}\}$. Using that $\{t_n\}$ is unbounded, choose a subsequence $\{t_{n_k}\}$ such that
$$
|t_{k}-t_{n_k}|>k.
$$
Let
$$
A=\sum_k E_{k,n_k}.
$$
It is straighforward to see that $A^*A\leq I$, and so $A$ is bounded. We have
\begin{align}
\|A-e^{ihT}Ae^{-ihT}\|
&=\Big\|\sum_k E_{k,n_k}-\sum_{n,m}\sum_k e^{ih(t_n-t_m)}E_{nn}E_{k,n_k}E_{mm}\Big\|\abajo
&=\Big\|\sum_k E_{k,n_k}-\sum_k E_{k,n_k}e^{ih(t_k-t_{n_k})}\,E_{k,n_k}\Big\|\abajo
&=\Big\|\sum_k (1-e^{ih(t_k-t_{n_k})})\,E_{k,n_k}\Big\|\abajo
&=\max\{|1-e^{ih(t_k-t_{n_k})}|:\ k\}
\end{align}
If we now consider the sequence $h_r=\frac\pi{t_r-t_{n_r}}$ then $h_r\to0$ and
$$
\|A-e^{ih_rT}Ae^{-ih_rT}\|\geq|1-e^{ih_r(t_r-t_{n_r})}|
=1-e^{i\pi}=2.
$$
So $\tau_t(A)$ is not continuous at $t=0$.

---

**How to get $T_0$.**

By the Spectral Theorem,
$$
T=\int_{\sigma(T)}\lambda\,dE(\lambda).
$$
Given $\e>0$, choose $\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb Z}$ to be a partition of $\mathbb R$ with $|a_{n+1}-a_n|<\e$. Form $I_n=[a_n,a_{n+1})$. Define $$f=\sum_n a_n\,1_{I_n}$$ and
$$ T_0=\int_{\sigma(T)}f(\lambda)\,dE(\lambda)=\sum_na_n\,E(I_n).
$$ By writing each $E(I_n)$ as a sum of pairwise orthogonal rank-one projections and repeating the corresponding $a_n$ accordingly, we get $(1)$. And from $\|\operatorname{id}-f\|_\infty<\e$,
$$
T-T_0=\sum_nTE(I_n)-a_nE(I_n),
$$
and
$$
a_nE(I_n)\leq\int_{I_n}\lambda\,dE(\lambda)=TE(I_n)\leq a_{n+1}E(I_n),
$$
we get
$$
\|T-T_0\|=\max\{\|TE(I_n)-a_nE(I_n)\|: n\}<\e.
$$

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed answer! I have two follow-up questions: 1. Is the existence of a discretized version of an unbounded operator, which is norm-close to the latter, a straightforward consequence of the spectral theorem? I have not seen something like that before, but only representations involving general spectral measures. 2. Could you give a hint regarding how the last step (involving the max) in the second to last equation can be justified?

Comment: I have edited some details in. As for your second question, try finding the norm of a diagonal matrix.

Comment: Many thanks for taking the time to provide these additional details! The hint regarding my second question was very helpful, and your construction of $T_0$ is surprisingly intuitive :D I do have one more question about the latter, though: isn't there some bound on $\vert a_{n+1} - a_n \vert$ needed in order to be able to get the estimate for the supremum norm? (I do not quite see where the $m$ you introduced is used.)

Comment: Yes, of course. The point is that $|a_{n+1}-a_n|<\varepsilon$.